# RaspberryPi program takes 100% cpu

Tags: raspbian, linux, performance, kernel

Why my program takes 100 % CPU even if its a helloworld program. Is it normal behavior?. Can anyone tell me the reason for this?. I am using debian wheezy.

Here is the screen shot of process..

[image]

Comment: usually this happens when you are stuck in an endless loop. If you are playing with threads try adding a sleep(ms) in the code.

Comment: If you post your code we may be able to suggest a simple alteration to fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's a good thing for a process to use 100% of the CPU. It means it finishes sooner.

It's a bad thing if it's an infinite loop or because it's polling like crazy instead of being event driven.

What *is* your helloworld program?

You can make it give up CPU to other processes more readily by using `nice`

```
$ nice ./helloworld
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply...My helloworld program first print Hello World and then enter in to infinite loop. Actually I was trying with multi threaded program with Ethernet server and client, which has more than one infinite loop.

Comment: @Haris, Not to worry, implementing this the wrong way will help you appreciate the elegance of right way when you get there.